# UDP in C: Send 1 million bytes from A to B

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I must send 1 million bytes from A to B through UDP protocol.
These 1 million bytes can be an array of random characters. I understood that it's not possible to send packets larger than 65507 bytes, and UDP, as you all know, does not guarantee the arrival of messages.

I thought about sending several characters from A to B, unless B will not reach 1 million. Next, B must send a flag to A as a confirmation. But also here, there aren't any guarantees that the "ack" has reached the A end-system.
There is also an additional end-system C, where I could implement some additional code, if I need to.

I thought to create 2 processes for each end-system, one to send and receive the million bytes, and the second to send and receive the flags.
I have tried to implement it, but I am not very convinced. An important requisite is to avoid busy waiting.

I need a little help to move forward.

Comment: If you need ack then why UDP?

Comment: What is the reason for not using TCP but trying to reimplement it using UDP?

Comment: You will need to deal with the issues that TCP deals with — sequencing, retries, acknowledgements, checksums, etc.  Since you can't tell from random data whether the data arrived in sequence, you'll have to impose sequencing on the segments of the data (because UDP doesn't guarantee in-order delivery any more than it guarantees delivery at all).

Comment: As you can see length of comment is directly proportional to user's rep. 21K (30 chars), 80K (77 chars), 300K (347 chars). It's not a case and I hope nothing else relates to this proportion...

Comment: So you basically want to implement TCP in UDP? You know it's still going to be (at best) the same speed as TCP, right?

Comment: Sorry for the question, I know what you're telling me, but it is an educational program, and the requirements of the text are these, but I'm finding it a little difficulty in solving. The data sent are random!

Comment: @user3195614 Actually, a lot of games use RUDP protocols to avoid the overhead of TCP.  TCP headers are huge, and the flow control isn't always desirable.

Comment: @JamesMcLauglin But the thing is, he doesn't need it. If he confirms the packages, it'll be easier and better off using TCP.

Comment: Given that you're required to do the exercise for a class, you're going to need to simulate a TCP session using UDP.  You'll need to: establish a connection (some UDP messages); split the data into sub-chunks that can be sent via UDP; include identification information with the sub-chunks so you know which order they're intended to be stored in; think about whether to include a checksum on the data so you know whether it arrives intact; close the connection when the transfer is finished; retry sections if a packet goes missing; ack repeated packets; etc.